# Batch PDF first page to PNG

Tags: windows, pdf, batch, adobe-acrobat

The problem sounds fairly simple: I have multiple PDF files and I want to extract the first page of each to a PNG file.

I created an action in Adobe Acrobat DC which is supposed to do the following:

- Delete all pages from 2 to 999 (because you can't tell it "Just keep page 1" or "Delete every page after number 1")
- Flatten all layers
- Export images to PNG

In my mind, this should work, but obviously it doesn't. It's like it only follows the third instruction, filling my export folder with hundreds of single images not *of* pages but *from* pages.

I'm quite lost here. If somebody could hint me on why my action is not working or at a way to achieve this, that would be awesome.

Have a nice day!

## Edit

A few things to know:

- I'm at work on company PC and can't install new software.
- I'm using Windows 10.
- I'm not a developer and am not comfortable with CLI, PHP, BATs and anything scripting.
- I can use the internet, so answers can make use of online tools.

---

**What I figured out since last time**

So I figured out the "Delete page 2 to 999" instruction wasn't working if the document had not at least 999 pages (and none of them had). I ran the script on a 23-pages document with the instruction "Delete pages 2 to 23" and it worked great, but, well, it would only work for 23 pages PDFs.

As for now I deleted the "Delete pages" instruction and manually delete pages other than 1 in the explorer. Needless to say this is ridiculously long and unoptimized.

Comment: You've not actually provided how you've setup the actions. You've said what you expect them to do, but as they aren't doing it, you've clearly not actually set them to do that. You can provide a screenshot of the setup or describe it clearly in your question.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I used to action creator panel and actually set up the different steps just as said - just checked to make sure: step 1 deletes pages 2 to 999 ; step 2 flattens layers and step 3 exports images to PNG. A screenshot wouldn't provide more information, really (plus, my Acrobat is in French).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you essentially want a PNG picture from the first page of the document?

Comment: @MaxWyss You indeed understood correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In this case, you could use Photoshop to create the PNG. You could create a JSX (aka JavaScript) file which opens the PDF with the parameters for the first page, and then saves it as PNG. With this, you would have correct rendering of the page, something other software may or may not properly accomplish.

Comment: @MaxWyss Wow, stupid me, how did I not think about Photoshop? It's much more appropriate for generating PNGs and I have enough knowledge to make batch actions... But somehow because I was dealing with PDF files I only thought of Acrobat. If you make that into an anwser I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An (actually quite obvious) approach would be using Photoshop.

Photoshop can open a given page and render it at configurable resolution with an appropriate color space. It will also properly render the page (something other software may have problems with). Writing out as PNG is also quite straightforward, and well configurable.

Because of the good support of JavaScript (aka Extendscript) and Applescript/VB, the whole workflow can be easily automatized, and be run as batch.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use Acrobat, but instead a simple PHP script targeting the `imagick` extension:

```
$i=new Imagick(); 
$i->readImage('path/to/your.pdf[0]'); 
$i->writeImage('/path/to/your.png');
```

Together with PHP's `glob` construct, you can easily loop over PDFs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I'm really not a PHP person, and more importantly I have no webserver availible to run this - and as I'm at work, I can't even install a WAMP (or any alternative) onto my PC thanks to company restrictions.

Comment: I recommended PHP to combine `glob` with the PNG generation. No need for WAMP, no need to install anything - you can run php.exe from a download folder without any installation

Answer (score 0):

The other guy said to use php imagemagick, but from the linux commandline, the imagemagick conversion binary is called convert. If I have a 5 page pdf in Doc/pdf/test.pdf, and I need to make Doc/png/testpage1.png, the command is as follows: `convert Doc/pdf/test.pdf Doc/png/test.png`
The leaves you with

> Doc/pdf/test.pdf
>
> Doc/png/test1.png
>
> Doc/png/test2.png
>
> Doc/png/test3.png
>
> Doc/png/test4.png
>
> Doc/png/test5.png

Converting a multiple page pdf into png breaks the file into pages.

Imagemagick = /usr/bin/convert

EDIT: Tested commenter solution on arch linux.
Solution `convert Doc/pdf/test.pdf[0] Doc/png/test.png`

Comment: Need to add -flatten switch and don't forget page 1 only, confirm your results please.

Comment: On my machine, creating the result above did not require flatten. To do page one only, I would do convert test.pdf test.png and then rm every file above 1. maybe `mv test1.png ../` `rm *` `mv ../test1.png .`

Comment: You can just use `convert Doc/pdf/test.pdf[0] Doc/png/test.png` (at least on mymachine, Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Well a few things bother me here: first you use Linux and my company PC is running Windows (my mistake, should have said it in the OP. Edited.), and second you have to manually enter the file path. The thing is, my PDFs are in dozens of subfolders (not my fault, I did not create these but now have to deal with them...), have long and unpractical names and, moreover, there really are a lot of them. I'd rather make the actions one by one in Acrobat.

Comment: @Ctouw There are bash emulation options available. If your company is on windows 10, ask your administrator to help you install the anniversary bash update. That should enable you to use utilities like /usr/bin/find . -type f -name *.pdf -exec convert {}[0] Doc/png/firstpage.png \; 
Cygwin may also be able to accpomplish this. I don't have your same situation, so y advice has to end here.

Comment: [How to convert a PDF into JPG with command line in Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085889/how-to-convert-a-pdf-into-jpg-with-command-line-in-linux).